# How to select random uniform samples inside a non-regular region of interest?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I am trying to extract N samples from a non-regular region from an image, delimited by a contour, I do have the positions of the contour pixels. The extracted samples must to follow a random uniform distribution. This is what I have:

[image]

And this is what I wish:

[image]

Any idea of how to do it?
cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Create a random uniform distribution over the bounding rectangle, draw from that, and reject any points that land outside the region of interest.

(The results won't be anti-clustered like the points in your example, but one thing at a time.)

Comment: I just edited my question, because I'm really interested in selecting exactly N samples from my ROI, and this is my real problem, any idea of how to do it?

Comment: @AlexanderDeLeonVI - You can also create a `std::vector` of points that contain the interior of the shape (perhaps with using `cv::drawContours`), then randomly sample from that vector instead.

Comment: @rayryeng - That could be a solution, also I tried to attached that in my code, but I'm not getting a well uniform distributed extraction. I still looking for another thing no matter how sophisticated it could be, thanks anyway.

Comment: @AlexanderDeLeonVI - Another suggestion I can make is to perhaps use the distance transform where the already sampled points from the interior contour act as seed pixels and the rest of the values are the distance to the nearest sampled point.  The larger the distance, the more farther away one point is away from a sampled point.  You could perhaps use the distances as some form of weights and sample from the interior shape points using weighted sampling based on these distances.  Either way, what you are asking for isn't easy.

Comment: @AlexanderDeLeonVI: This is a simple solution; if you can't get it to work, more sophisticated approaches are not likely to succeed. Can you generate points with a uniform distribution over the rectangle? Can you distinguish between points inside the ROI and points outside?

Comment: @Beta : I tested your idea, but it isn't what I need, because in most of the cases the points tend to appear in a non uniform distribution and that is not desirable because I need to use the points in a posterior stage, and your option doesn't fit my needing. Thanks for your support.

Comment: My comment about anti-clustering was tongue-in-cheek, but perhaps I should spell it out. *How do you know the points you got were in a non-uniform distribution?* Uniformly distributed points look clustered to the human eye, and the points in your example, which may look uniformly distributed to you, are actually anti-clustered. It is possible -- actually highly likely -- that what you are asking for is not what you have in mind.